# SQLAlchemy read-only Oracle connection

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

This question is similar to [Oracle read-only JDBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287482/oracle-read-only-jdbc-connection) but using SQLAlchemy instead of JDBC

I am trying to set a connection to oracle using SQLAlchemy in read-only mode. The reason is that I want to be sure that nothing can be changed unintentionally when using SQLAlchemy whereas the data in database can be modified by other programs.

Other users suggested to create a new user and give them grants on select in order to allow it to read from the existing tables. Despite this may be a valid approach in many cases, the aim of my question is to do it from SQLAlchemy, without changing anything in the database.

Is there a way to set connection parameters for oracle like `READONLY` in `create_engine()` or `connect()` functions in SQLAlchemy? If yes, how is it done?

Comment: i think , if you create a user in oracle DB and give user specific grants, it will give you what you need, this kind of solution is acceptable for you ?

Comment: `sqlalchemy` will connect to the database with the credentials you provide. If such credentials are allowed to create or modify things, they will be able to do it. You have to use a credentials of a database user without any writing privilege of any kind

Comment: @AliFidanli Yes, in the case a new user can be created the best approach is to create it with 'grant select' to the tables I want to read from. The aim of the question is trying to be minimally intrusive in the existing DB, avoiding to add/touch/edit anything.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez please see my answer to Ali Fidanli comment.

Comment: @aturegano, you are using the wrong approach to the issue. You are not intrusively doing anything in the DB, it is quite the opposite. You are avoiding problems in the future. If you give a db user with privileges, it does not matter what you do in `sqlalchemy`, anyone will be able to do whatever this db user is allowed to. From an architectural point of view you are trying to apply security in the wrong layer.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez In the 99.99% [or a little bit more ;-) ] of times your approach is the good one. Yes, my approach is a terrible idea as DB design but in this case I am looking for different objectives: I should not use DDL sentences and I want to assure that SQLAlchemy shall not apply any change, neither by DML nor by DDL statements with an user that is allowed to do such changes in DB. I am an SQLAlchemy newbie and for the time being I want to use this as a safeguard.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the comments, here is a simple way to create a limited read only user:

1. create user and give session grant

---

```
CREATE USER app_user IDENTIFIED BY app_user DEFAULT TABLESPACE users TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;

GRANT CREATE SESSION to app_user
```

2. Create role to give select only priv. next step

---

```
CREATE ROLE ro_role;
```

3. give select grants to tables from desired schema

---

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM dba_tables WHERE owner='SCHEMA_NAME')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON schema_name.' || x.table_name || 
                                  ' TO ro_role';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

4. give grant to user using role we created

---

```
GRANT ro_role TO app_user;
```